# md-tabs : unable to see pagination arrows when number of tabs exceeds

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am new to angularJS, I am trying md-tabs to create an items page, where each item is a tab on the page listing its details, here is my HTML code:

```
<md-content class="md-padding">
        <md-tabs  md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom="" md-autoselect="">
            <md-tab ng-repeat="itemTab in itemList" label="{{itemTab.name}}">
                <div style="padding: 35px; text-align: left;">
                    <div ng-repeat="detail in itemTab.details">
                       <p><pre>{{detail.info}}</pre></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
    </md-content>
```

Here when the number of items increases, more than it can show on the page there is no pagination arrow that would help me to scroll to next set of items, can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably related to you css. Try including the angular material css only and try if it works.